# Why does this Image averaging just generates vertical lines?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create a program that averages image's pixel values, but so far it has just generated vertical lines.

This is my code so far:

```py
from typing import List

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def main():
    # Importing two of the same imagae for debugigng purposes
    a = cv.imread("Datasets/OTIS/OTIS_PNG_Gray/Fixed Patterns/Pattern1/Pattern1_001.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    b = cv.imread("Datasets/OTIS/OTIS_PNG_Gray/Fixed Patterns/Pattern1/Pattern1_001.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    s = [a, b]
    avg = [[0] * len(a[0])] * len(a)
    print(f"rows: {len(a)} cols: {len(a[0])}")
    print(f"rows: {len(avg)} cols: {len(avg[0])}")

    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            # print(f"({i}, {j}): {temp_mean(s, i, j)}")
            avg[i][j] = temp_mean(s, i, j) / 255

    avim = np.array(avg)
    print(f"rows: {len(avim)} cols: {len(avim[0])}")

    cv.imshow("title", avim)

    cv.waitKey(0)


def temp_mean(seq: List[List[List[any]]], i: int, j: int):
    out = 0

    for im in seq:
        out += im[i][j]

    return out / len(seq)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Source Image:
[image: Source Image]

Image generated:
[image: Image generated]

Comment: Seems like you are averaging across one dimension only (either rows or columns). What is the shape of the output array?

Comment: What is wrong with using cv2.GaussianBlur or a box blur. Why write it from scratch. Less efficient.

Comment: @fmw42 It is not intended to be a blurring algorithm, and I also need complete control over what happens to the images

Comment: If you want to average all pixel values, use `np.mean`. Don’t write loops in Python if you don’t need to. Also, `a` and `b` are not lists of lists, they are NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your problem is `avg` being defined as a list of copies of one list. When you update one list (row), you update them all. Thus, the output image has all identical rows.

You really should be using NumPy arrays to represent an image:

```py
avg = np.zeros(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that avg is a shallow copy of a, created by the * multiplication.
This means that avg contains multiple references to the same row in a, so when you update avg[i][j], you're actually modifying a[i][j] as well.
The result is that every row of avg ends up containing identical values - the last row of a that you modified.
To fix this, create a deep copy of a for avg using:
avg = [row[:] for row in a]

This will create a new list for each row, resulting in distinct data that can be modified independently

Comment: `avg` is not a copy of `a`. `a` is a NumPy array, `avg` is a list of lists, where the inner lists are all copies of each other, and filled with zeros initially.